# converting TFlearn model to Keras - Python 3.7

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tflearn

I am trying to convert the following TFlearn code to Keras (since I m using tensorflow2.0, TFlearn is not compatible) - I am fairly new to both FWorks so I don t really know why it is not working (accuracy stays at 0.04 after 1000 epochs)

in the original TFlearn shape, I have traning[0] inputs, and output[0] outputs, and 2X 8 hidden layers in between

here is the TFlearn model

```
tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save("model.tflearn")
```

and here is the Keras Conversion

```
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

# define the keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', input_shape=(len(training[0]),)))

model.add(Dense(8, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(len(output[0]), activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(training,output, epochs=100, batch_size=20)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the TFlearn version is learning properly and the Keras version isn't?

Comment: yes totally. I am trainning an array of bag of words (always the same BOW size). Reaching .95 accuracy on TFlearn

Comment: What loss is tflearn using? For classification you should not be using mean squared error, prefer categorical cross-entropy

Comment: I ve tried first using Categorical-cross-entropy, but with the same results, TFlearn had no loss specification ... so, I m lost

Comment: @YannMassard have you found any solution? I am facing the same problem, the loss of the Keras model is higher than the tflearn model!

Answer (score 0):

In the keras code you wrote for 100 epochs and not 1000 epochs